# How did Osiris-Rex enter orbit around asteroid Bennu?

Tags: orbit, osiris-rex, bennu

Bennu became the smallest and probably least massive celestial body orbited by a probe. Its surface gravity is 6 micro-g (= 6 millionths the gravity of Earth) according to Wikipedia. How did a probe manage to enter an orbit around a body with microgravity in the first place? The probe must have decelerated extremely and its instruments must be very sensitive. How was that achieved?

Comment: different but related questions: [How low does OSIRIS REx's record-setting orbiting around Bennu go?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33262/12102) and the currently unanswered [Could ejecta from asteroid Bennu enter into temporary orbit around it? If so, how?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40291/12102)